# Text is flowing out of the container when zooming

Tags: html, css

My button's text leaks out of the container if I zoom it. When I zoom the button's text flows out of the container. What I want is for it to adjust its font size and stay in the container and don't leak out.

```css
.wrapper a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 8.5vw;
  height: 7vh;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #05386b;
  border: 2px solid #05386b;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.wrapper a span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wrapper a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #EDF5E1;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.wrapper a:hover {
  color: #8ee4af;
}

.wrapper a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div className="wrapper">
  <Link to="/orders"><span>Returns <br/> <b>& Orders</b></span></Link>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work: It looks like you're not using regular html. You should either change it to regular html (`<a href="/orders"><span>Returns <br/> <b>& Orders</b></span></a>`) or include whatever libraries are necessary to use this html.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [`@media`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) css rule. It can be used to create responsive webpages.
For example the following increases the font size by 2 pixels if the screen size is smaller than 786px.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 786px) {
    .wrapper a {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

To prevent the content from overflowing all together you might want to take a look at the [`overflow`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) css property. It controls the way content overflows from the containing area. Might not be applicable to your case though as you are talking about making a button here.